# ¿Cómo poder verificar diagonales en el problema de las 8 reinas?

Tags: python, matrices, algoritmos, matriz

Buenass, es la primera vez que escribo una pregunta, así que espero que sea entendible lo que planteo.

Estoy desarrollando una solución interactiva para el problema de las 8 reinas, en este caso, cuando colocamos una reina en una coordenada dada por el usuario, las columnas, filas y diagonales colindantes se "bloquean", actualmente verifico las posiciones utilizando una función para filas y columnas, y 4 para las diagonales, teniendo diagonales superiores e inferiores, quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de verificar estas últimas sin tomar tantas líneas de código

```
def crear_tablero():
    tablero = [
        [" ", " ", " ", " "," ", " ", " ", " "],
        [" ", " ", " ", " "," ", " ", " ", " "],
        [" ", " ", " ", " "," ", " ", " ", " "],
        [" ", " ", " ", " "," ", " ", " ", " "],
        [" ", " ", " ", " "," ", " ", " ", " "],
        [" ", " ", " ", " "," ", " ", " ", " "],
        [" ", " ", " ", " "," ", " ", " ", " "],
        [" ", " ", " ", " "," ", " ", " ", " "],
    ]
    return tablero

def imprimir_tablero(tablero):
    for i in tablero:
        print(i)

def diagonal_arriba(fila, columna, tablero):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while fila + 1 - i > 0 and columna + 1 - j > 0:
        tablero[fila - i][columna - j] = "*"
        i += 1
        j += 1
    return tablero

def diagonal_abajo(fila, columna, tablero):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while fila + i < 8 and columna + j < 8:
        tablero[fila + i][columna +j] = "*"
        i += 1
        j += 1
    return tablero

def diagonal_abajo2(fila, columna, tablero): 
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while fila + 1 - i > 0 and columna + j < 8:
        tablero[fila - i][columna + j] = "*"
        i += 1
        j += 1
    return tablero

def diagonal_arriba2(fila, columna, tablero): 
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while fila + i < 8 and columna + 1 - j > 0:
        tablero[fila + i][columna - j] = "*"
        i += 1
        j += 1

    tablero[fila][columna] = "R"
    return tablero

def definir_espacios(tablero, fila, columna):
    for i in range(8):
        if tablero[fila][i] != "*":
            tablero[fila][i] = "*"
        if tablero[i][columna] != "*":
            tablero[i][columna] = "*"

def jugar():
    tablero = crear_tablero()
    reinas = 8
    while True:
        print(f"Reinas restantes: {reinas}")
        imprimir_tablero(tablero)
        fila = int(input("Elige una fila (0 a 7): "))
        columna = int(input("Elige una columna (0 a 7): "))
        if fila > 7 and columna > 7:
            print("Opción invalida")
            continue
        if tablero[fila][columna] != "*" and tablero[fila][columna] == " ":
            definir_espacios(tablero, fila, columna)  
            diagonal_abajo(fila, columna, tablero)
            diagonal_arriba(fila, columna, tablero)
            diagonal_abajo2(fila, columna, tablero)
            diagonal_arriba2(fila, columna, tablero)
            reinas -= 1
        else:
            print("Esa casilla no es accesible")
            continue
        if reinas == 0:
            print("Terminaste el juego!")
            imprimir_tablero(tablero)
            break

jugar()
```

La salida actual

```
['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'R', '*', '*']
['*', 'R', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*']
['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'R', '*']
['R', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*']
['*', '*', '*', 'R', '*', '*', '*', '*']
['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'R']
['*', '*', '*', '*', 'R', '*', '*', '*']
['*', '*', 'R', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*']
```

Comment: Las diagonales se calculan con una funcion simple... fijate que todas las diagonales son, o la suma de sus coordenadas, o la resta de sus coordenadas... verificalo, y la proxima, google ;)

Answer (score -4):

El problema de poner 8 reinas en un tablero de ajedrez no se puede resolver con las 8 reinas, pero sí se puede dividir en 8 problemas mas pequeños:

Poner dos reinas en el mismo tablero sin que se maten.

El tablero, como sabemos, tiene 8x8 casillas.
Luego ponemos una reina en la posición A y la otra reina en la posición B, tanto A como B son mayores a 0 y menores a 65.

Aconsejo hacer el tablero con lápiz y papel y enumerar las casillas para poder pensar más fácilmente en el problema.

La reina mata de forma horizontal, vertical y en diagonal.
En forma horizontal, significa que si A y B son casillas entre 0 y 65, las reinas en diagonal matan si uno esta en una casilla adicional a la reina en múltiplos de 7 u 8 u 9.

Pensemos que hay una reina en la posición 30, podrá matar en diagonal a las casillas 3,12,21,16,23,37,44,51,58,39 y 48 frente a la 30 la diferencia es que es un múltiplo de 7 o de 9.
Podemos comprobar los múltiplos cuando la operación módulo da igual a 0.

Aquí es al revés: si la diferencia entre A y B es múltiplo de 7 o de 9, las casillas A y B están en diagonal y por tanto se matan, que es lo que hay que evitar.

Para dos casillas A y B en el tablero de ajedrez de 8x8:

```py
if ((A-B)%7) == 0 return "SE MATAN"
if ((A-B)%9) == 0 return "SE MATAN"
```

Lo otro que quedaría por hacer es un ciclo que pase por cada casilla y evalúe si la diferencia con la casilla donde está la reina, es múltiplo de 7 o de 9.

Si la diferencia es múltiplo de 8, es porque están en la misma columna luego tampoco serviría, porque es como matan las torres, en forma vertical y horizontal.

Matan Horizontal si la diferencia es `abs(A-B)<=7`.

Matan Vertical `if ((A-B)%8) == 0`.

Matan en diagonal `if ((A-B)%7) == 0 || ((A-B)%9) == 0`.

Comment: Y esto no es una respuesta.. es mas, no es nada...

Comment: Te sugerimos revisar [answer] para que conozcas como realizar respuestas en el sitio.

Comment: ¡Esto es un comentario larguísimo! Lee [answer]. No pidas disculpas: ¡directo al grano!

Comment: multiplos??? modulo??? primos??? si tu array de reinas (que es un solo array) tienen dos coordenadas, el indice (como fila) y la columna (como valor) alcanza con verificar que no hay dos en la misma columna (en la fila no hay dos) y la diagonal se calcula como suma de indice mas valor, o como resta de indice mas valor, sin hacer mas... ponelo en lapiz y papel, vas a ver que si haces las cuentas, son siempre iguales esos valores ;)